# How to deal with mutually exclusive claims in policies to enforce four eyes principle

Tags: c#, identityserver4, asp.net-core-identity

I am trying to configure two policies which can only have one of two claims to enforce a four eyes principle:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
                {
                    options.AddPolicy("CreditApprover", //An approver is not allowed to review.
                        policy => policy.RequireAssertion(ctx =>
                            ctx.User.HasClaim(claim => claim.Value == "CreditLoanApprover") &&
                            !ctx.User.HasClaim(claim => claim.Value == "CreditLoanReviewer")));

                    options.AddPolicy("CreditReviewer", //A reviewer is not allowed to approve.
                        policy => policy.RequireAssertion(ctx =>
                            !ctx.User.HasClaim(claim => claim.Value == "CreditLoanApprover") &&
                            ctx.User.HasClaim(claim => claim.Value == "CreditLoanReviewer")));
                });
```

I've added the `Authorize` attribute to the controller actions:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "CreditApprover")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Approve()
{
    // ...
}

[Authorize(Policy = "CreditReviewer")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Review()
{
    // ...
}
```

But if I give two different users both claims, they are still able to review their own approvals. I want these users be unable to do so. Should this be possible like this, or do I need to build a custom `AuthorizationHandler`?

Comment: It seems every thing is OK, Probably you are missing something.

Comment: Not sure what happened. Perhaps I messed up the claims I gave myself. Seems to work as written above a day later :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works as described in the post itself. Probably missed something while configuring my claims during testing.